# How to make inner table with general title in Aspose?

Tags: c#, .net, aspose

How can I make table with columns like this using Aspose Words?

[Image There](http://i003.radikal.ru/1509/48/1adb4d0e958e.png) (can't attach , have not rating)

HEADER,FIRST,SECOND.

I tried to make table with 3 cells(header,first,second) and insert it in cell. But it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

Please use following code example to generate the required table. I suggest you please read about 'Working with merged cells' from here:

http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/wordsnet/Working+with+Merged+Cells

```
Document doc = new Document();
DocumentBuilder builder = new DocumentBuilder(doc);

builder.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Center;

//Start table
builder.StartTable();

builder.InsertCell();
builder.CellFormat.VerticalMerge = CellMerge.First;
builder.Write("One");

builder.InsertCell();
builder.CellFormat.VerticalMerge = CellMerge.First;
builder.Write("Two");

builder.InsertCell();
builder.CellFormat.VerticalMerge = CellMerge.None;
builder.CellFormat.HorizontalMerge = CellMerge.First;
builder.Write("Header");

builder.InsertCell();
builder.CellFormat.HorizontalMerge = CellMerge.Previous;
builder.Write("Header");

builder.InsertCell();
builder.CellFormat.HorizontalMerge = CellMerge.None;
builder.CellFormat.VerticalMerge = CellMerge.First;
builder.Write("Column");

builder.InsertCell();
builder.CellFormat.VerticalMerge = CellMerge.First;
builder.Write("Column");
builder.EndRow();

//Insert second Row
builder.InsertCell();
builder.CellFormat.VerticalMerge = CellMerge.Previous;
builder.Write("One");

builder.InsertCell();
builder.CellFormat.VerticalMerge = CellMerge.Previous;
builder.Write("Two");

builder.InsertCell();
builder.CellFormat.VerticalMerge = CellMerge.None;
builder.Write("First");

builder.InsertCell();
builder.CellFormat.VerticalMerge = CellMerge.None;
builder.Write("Second");

builder.InsertCell();
builder.CellFormat.VerticalMerge = CellMerge.Previous;
builder.Write("Column");

builder.InsertCell();
builder.CellFormat.VerticalMerge = CellMerge.Previous;
builder.Write("Column");
builder.EndRow();

builder.CellFormat.VerticalMerge = CellMerge.None;
builder.CellFormat.HorizontalMerge = CellMerge.None;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    builder.InsertCell();
    builder.Write("Cell 1");

    builder.InsertCell();
    builder.Write("Cell 2");

    builder.InsertCell();
    builder.Write("Cell 3");

    builder.InsertCell();
    builder.Write("Cell 4");

    builder.InsertCell();
    builder.Write("Cell 5");

    builder.InsertCell();
    builder.Write("Cell 6");
    builder.EndRow();
}

//End the table
builder.EndTable();

doc.Save(MyDir + "Out.docx");
```

I work with Aspose as Developer evangelist.